# Java program enter string of all lowercase characters, convert the lowercase character at index position to the uppercase character

Tags: java, string

Use scanner class and need to non negative integer

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: Please share the source code

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions like `charAt(int index)` and `toUpperCase()`. For more infos use the api search.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="test";

System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
```

output is same as

```
System.out.println("test".toUpperCase());
```

output is

> TEST

`charAt(index)` is a String object method, instance method.

```
System.out.println("test".charAt(0));
```

output is

> t

To make one character to upper case you need to use character method. `Character.toUpperCase( character)` is also a static method. [What is static method?](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24034/static-method)
In Java, a static method is a method that belongs to a class rather than an instance of a class.

Here is example.

```
System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase("test".charAt(0)));
String s="test1";
System.out.println( Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(s.length())));
```

output is

> T
>
> 1